# What is included in the VFS $75 walk in service?

Tags: visas, uk, vfs-global

I am in the same boat as everybody. I went to an ASC on the 1st of April 2019 only to know that service across all ASC's are suspended for UK visas.

I have to travel within 15 days and now I don't have many options left, although I saw 'walk-in' without appointment service at premium application centres. I believe it is 75$ per application.

Does anybody have any idea on what is covered by this $75 walk in appointment service? Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: "is it worth it" is only a question you can answer. but the rest about what services are included in the charge is probably something one of our UK Visa experts can answer.

Answer (score 4):

There is a service for $75 to allow walk ins, but it is only applicable if you have already purchased a premium package and are using it as an add on, the Bronze premium package is $410. It allows you to not only walk in without an appointment, but also outside of the 1pm-3pm appointment times.

As stated on the [VFS Website](https://www.vfsglobal.co.uk/us/en/premium-services/walk-in-without-appointment):

> This service is only available as an add-on when you buy a Silver
>   Premium Package or Bronze Premium Package for additional $75.

If you wanted to purchase a premium package they also include application and document checks, courier services, SMS services, and some packages prioritise your application.